# Does GitBook created a merge request before updating Gitlab?

Tags: integration, gitbook

We would like to adopt GitBook to create our documentation, and integrate it with our GitLab repo. I understand the integration is bi-directional, but I want to find out whether, when we update GitBook, the new information is pushed to our Gitlab repo automatically or we first get a merge request.

Comment: We're very busy. Its a lot of work to install, configure, link, and test. Would be better if we knew the answer before we committed. Our purchase hinges on the answer.

Comment: Please speak more literally so I understand your point. Stack Overflow is designed to answer questions.